# Fragment does not respond to onClick event on custom views

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, listener, android-custom-view

I have MainFragment, and inside my fragment I added my CustomButton custom view. And, onViewCreated, I setOnClickListener to the view. But, the fragmenet does not respond to the click.

ButtonWithImage

```
class ButtonWithImage(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : LinearLayout(context, attrs) {

    init {
        val view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_custom_btn, this)

        val attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.BadgeIcon)

        view.btn_image.setImageDrawable(attributes.getDrawable(R.styleable.BadgeIcon_image))
        view.btn_text.setText(attributes.getResourceId(R.styleable.BadgeIcon_text, 0))

        attributes.recycle()
    }

}
```

fragment_main.xml

```
...
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <corn.transaction.custom_view.ButtonWithImage
                android:id="@+id/my_cards"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:image="@drawable/ic_my_cards"
                app:text="@string/btn_text_my_cards"/>

        <corn.transaction.custom_view.ButtonWithImage
                android:id="@+id/transactions"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:image="@drawable/ic_transactions"
                app:text="@string/btn_text_transactions"/>

    </LinearLayout>
...
```

MainFragment.kt

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        my_cards.setOnClickListener { logMessage("loooooog") }
    }
```

Comment: where you implement click listener ?

Comment: Can you please post code for `logMessage`

Comment: You should have added `item_custom_btn` too, but it's probably just `setClickable(true); setFocusable(true);` missing in `ButtonWithImage` constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimal solution is making all views in `XML` clickable and focusable false.

You can use the following code:

```
my_cards.setOnClickListener { logMessage("loooooog") }
```

As all views are not clickable and focusable, they do ignore clicks, but not the custom view itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can fix it by:

1. Adding `focusable=false` and `clickable=false` to your `btn_image` and `btn_text`
2. Adding `focusable=true` and `clickable=true` to your root view of this custom layout (also give it id -> lets say `custom_button_container`)
3. call `my_cards.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.custom_button_container).setOnClickListener { logMessage("loooooog") }`